# Open ball is an open set.

Tags: general-topology

Could someone please show that an open ball is open where the definition of "open" is: A set is open if for each $x$ in $U$ there is an open rectangle $A$ such that $x$ in $A$ is contained in $U$. Where an open rectangle is $(a_1,b_1)\times\ldots\times(a_n,b_n)$. I also realize that one can use rectangles or balls, but I would like to see the proof using rectangles, as this is the definition used in Spivak's calculus on manifolds.  So for example, the solution located at [An open ball is an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104083/an-open-ball-is-an-open-set) is unacceptable.

Comment: you do exactly that proof, and then, put a cube inside the ball....

Comment: that would only be a(n) (infinite) regression.  If all I have to do is put a cube (rectangle) inside that ball, then I would have the same problem: How to put the cube inside the ball that's inside the large ball.
I want a rigorous proof that it can be done.

Comment: @user29507:  the farthest point of a cube of side $\delta$ from the center is $\sqrt n \frac \delta{2^n}$  So if you can put an $\epsilon$ ball in, you can put a $\delta$ cube in for small enough $\delta$.

Comment: .... right, that seems very clever, but unfortunately I don't "see" \sqrt n \frac \delta{2^n} very well.  Its probably just some basic n-dim geometry, but as I'm just beginning at this, I don't understand.

Comment: actually the value that I compute in R^2 and R^3 is sqrt(n)*delta/2.   Not divided by 2^n.  I don't know how to do the computation in R^4 because I can't visualize that space.  Any other ideas would be much appreciated.