# Show that unbounded open ball is an open set.

Tags: metric-spaces

Show that unbounded open ball
$$B=\{y:d(x,y)>r\}$$
 is an open set.

In the case of bounded open ball 
$$B=\{y:d(x,y)<r\}$$
using  triangle inequality we can easily [show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104083/an-open-ball-is-an-open-set) that, it is indeed an open set. But I left helpless, when I try to use the same technique for unbounded open ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't state which definition of openness you're referring to, i'll use this one: A set $A$ is open if for all $a \in A$ there exists an open (bounded) ball $B$ such that $a \in B \subseteq A$.

Now, let $B' = \{ y : d(x,y) > r\}$ and $b \in B'$. Let $r' := d(x,b) -r > 0$. Then we claim that $\{y: d(b,y) < r'\} \subseteq B'$. Take $y$ such that $d(b,y) < r'$. Then

$$d(x,y) + r' > d(x,y) + d(y,b) \geq d(x,b) = r + r'$$
Hence, $d(x,y) > r$, i.e. $y \in B'$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space; let $x \in M$. Then $d(x, \cdot): M \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous on $M$. If $r \geq 0$, then $]r, \infty[$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$; hence the preimage of $]r, \infty[$ under $d(x, \cdot)$ is open in $M$.

Comment: To be honest, your answer is complicated than the question(to me). Could you give me an explanation please?

Comment: @Sucre It can be proved that every metric defined on a set $M$ is continuous on $M \times M$.

Comment: @Sucre I believe you can some proof of that claim at this S.E.. :)